# Matlab - How can I transform a set of cell arrays into an array that allows indexing?

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array

I am struggling with this problem for a day and cannot find a solution anywhere online. I have four cell arrays with data per country on which I perform operations to find a number of countries that I want to analyse. I have saved these countries in a 27x1 cell array with nonnumerical attributes whose output looks like:

```
'Belgium'
'Bulgaria'
'Croatia'
'Cyprus'
'Czechia'
'Denmark'
'Estonia'
```

This is an example of the rows that I want to subtract from other cell arrays with data per country. The problem is that cell arrays do not allow indexing which means that I cannot use these to subtract data from other cell arrays. **So what I want as output is an array that allows indexing such that I can use that array to subtract information of other cell arrays.**

What I have tried:

- I have tried str2double to create rows that allow indexing. This
  resulted in NaN values which did not allow any operation
- I have tried    cell2mat which gave the error: Dimensions of arrays
  being    concatenated are not consistent.
- I have tried to create a table from    cell arrays, but I couldent
  paste all the data in it from the    different cell arrays because I
  couldent subtract it

I am new here so I dont know how I can append my .m file and cell arrays. Therefore, I add a part of my code here:

```
[~,ia,ib] = intersect(pop(:,1),gdp(:,1));
Com_popgdp = [pop(ia,1:2),gdp(ib,2)];

[~,ia,ib] = intersect(fp(:,1),lr(:,1));
Com_fplr = [fp(ia,1:2),lr(ib,2)];

[~,ia,ib] = intersect(Com_popgdp(:,1),Com_fplr(:,1));
Com_all = [Com_popgdp(ia,1:2),Com_fplr(ib,2)]; 

Com_all = Com_all(:,1);

%Com_all is the resulting cell array with all countries that I want to
%analyse resulting from the intersections of cell arrays. For the analysis, 
%I must extract the Com_all rows from
%pop/gdp/fp/lr. However, this is not possible with cell arrays. How can I
%access and extract the rows from pop/gdp/fp/lr for my analysis?
```

Could anyone help me find a way in which I can use the selection cell arrays as indexing to subtract data from other cell arrays? 
Which method would be appropriate?

Comment: How are the initial cell arrays getting created? Are you reading them in from a file. Are they hard coded in the script somewhere?
My initial thought is that you should create a table with columns for each variable: country name, GDP, etc. Initialize it with all of the countries from all of the datasets and NaNs for the numeric data. Than fill in the missing values that you have. Then only keep rows without NaNs. If you can find a way to share the data I will post an answers with more explicit details.

Comment: Hi goryh, thanks for replying. I downloaded .tsv files from Eurostat statistics. These are translated by a `tsv2cell` function in Matlab and from then I use standard Matlab operations.

Comment: How can I add such part of data? The countries that I provided are not sufficient?

Comment: Instead of creating a new question, you should have edited [your old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58749730/matlab-how-convert-cell-array-to-double) so it can be reopenend. Note that the system will automatically ban you from asking questions if you have too many negatively-received questions, so it is always best to improve your questions than to ignore and/or delete them.

Comment: Hi Cris, I thought that it was closed and could not be reopened. Thanks your input!

Comment: "cell arrays do not allow indexing [...]" This is false. You can index into cell arrays just like any other array. If you want to index your data using the country name, for example `data.Belgium`, make a `struct`. You can then also use variables to index like so: `data.(country_name)`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks, I am not very familiar with creating structs. Can I make them for my four cell arrays and use the resulting cell array for subtracting data?

Comment: What does "subtracting data" mean? Do you want to remove rows from arrays? Or do you want to subtract values from other values?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I hope this will clarify. I have four cell arrays with different data for a  number of countries. Not all data is consistent, if so, the country will not be analysed and the rows will be erased. This results in a cell array only consisting of countries that can be analysed. I want to use the rows of these countries such that I can take/subtract data for these countries from the initial four cell arrays and create an array with all data required for my analysis.

Comment: Seems to me like you want to subtract numeric values which are stored for each country. Try to index/access the cells with notation like: `pop{:,1}`. These braces `{}` access the values. You used parentheses `()` which return cells. Maybe that helps...

Comment: @avermaet good point you make, I have seen it before. But by using curly brackets I cannot access values to add them to another cell array. Any idea how this is possible?

Edit: I tried adding data to a zero double array like this: data = zeros(length(Com_all),5);
data(:,1) = Com_all{:,1};
data(:,2) = pop{:,1};

Comment: You can use `[]`to concatenate arrays. If you want to add a cell to an existing cell array A, something similar to `A=[A {newDataHere}]` should work I belive. You only need to be careful with dimensions. If stuff like this is your problem, you will really benefit from reading the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you first want to compute the intersection of all lists of country names, then index the cell arrays accordingly. [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.intersect.html) finds the intersection of two lists, you can call it multiple times in sequence to intersect multiple lists. And [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) finds which of the selected countries is present. For example:

```matlab
A1 = {
'Bulgaria',2
'Croatia',3
'Cyprus',4
'Czechia',5
'Denmark',6
'Estonia',7
};

A2 = {
'Belgium',11
'Bulgaria',12
'Croatia',13
'Cyprus',14
'Denmark',16
'Estonia',17
};

A3 = {
'Belgium',21
'Croatia',23
'Cyprus',24
'Czechia',25
'Denmark',26
'Estonia',27
};

[countries] = intersect(A1(:,1),A2(:,1));
[countries] = intersect(countries,A3(:,1));
i1 = ismember(A1(:,1),countries); A1 = A1(i1,:);
i2 = ismember(A2(:,1),countries); A2 = A2(i2,:);
i3 = ismember(A3(:,1),countries); A3 = A3(i3,:);
A = [A1,A2(:,2),A3(:,2)];
```

The code above does assume that the three input cell arrays all have the countries in the same order. If this is not the case, sort the arrays using [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) before matching them up with the list of selected countries:

```matlab
i1 = ismember(sort(A1(:,1)),countries);
```

Comment: Hello Cris, thanks for you elaborate answer! Your understanding of my goal is correct and I think the ismember is the solution I was looking for. It took me some time to modify it for to implement specific columns. But this solution works! Thanks again and I have accepted your answer!

Comment: I do have one more question. Is there a way that I can reduce the number of lines in which the same operations are performed? Instead of 3 ismember lines, I use four which perform the same operation. Can this be simplified by implementing a loop?

Comment: @WouterWizard: If you do `A={A1,A2,A3,A4}` you can then address the arrays as `A{i}`, which you can use in a loop.

Comment: Great, it works perfect! Thanks for your commitment!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution than I initially thought.

First, change our cell arrays into tables

```
gdp = cell2table(gdp,'VariableNames',{'country','gdp'})
```

Or you could read them in directly as tables (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html).

As long as all the tables have the same name for column with the country name you can then use [innerjoin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/innerjoin.html) to it the intersection of the tables based on the country.

Here is the example I run to test it:

```
gdp = {'Belgium',1;'Bulgaria',2;'Croatia',3};
pop = {'Croatia',30; 'Cyprus', 40; 'Czechia', 50};
gdp = cell2table(gdp,'VariableNames',{'country','gdp'})
gdp =

  3×2 table

     country      gdp
    __________    ___

    'Belgium'      1 
    'Bulgaria'     2 
    'Croatia'      3 

popTable = cell2table(pop,'VariableNames',{'country','pop'})
pop =

  3×2 table

     country     pop
    _________    ___

    'Croatia'    30 
    'Cyprus'     40 
    'Czechia'    50

innerjoin(gdpTable,popTable)
1×3 table

     country     gdp    pop
    _________    ___    ___

    'Croatia'     3     30
```

Comment: Thanks goryh! I try to implement this in my script and let you know if it solves the problem

Comment: I receive an error because I cannot translate the cell arrays into tables. I tried this with the gdp array: gdp = cell2table(gdp,'VariableNames','gdp'); which gave the error:

Error using cell2table (line 69)
The VariableNames property is a cell array of character vectors. To assign multiple variable names, specify names in a
string array or a cell array of character vectors.

Comment: The third argument in the cell2table needs to be a cell array. Putting `'gdp'` will throw an error. Putting `{'gdp'}` will not (at least not the same error). If you do not have a name for very column in you will also get an error, hence my example: `cell2table(gdp,'VariableNames',{'country','gdp'})`

Comment: It is not letting me edit my comment. Let's try that last sentence again:
 If you do not have a name for very column in the data, you will also get an error, hence my example named both columns: `cell2table(gdp,'VariableNames',{'country','gdp'})`

Comment: Goryh, I had to sleep a night to fully understand and implement it. Now, after some modifications I have the gdp table. I work on modifying the other cell arrays and then try to innerjoin them. Many thanks!